# Will someone explain this Swift 4 problem dealing with Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: repeats: block:{})

Tags: swift, timer

So, I start out by creating my label that is red.

I want to create a timer that changes the color to dark grey every second, and then back to red the next second.

I figured I could create a timer with a time interval of 1 or 2 seconds, have it repeat, and change the labels text color within the block.

I get an error saying:

> "Instance member 'aLabelThatIsRed' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'"

It won't let me change the label though. Why?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var aLabelThatIsRed: UILabel!

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        let darkGrey = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.05, green: 0.05, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1.0)
        aLabelThatIsRed.textColor = darkGrey
    }
```

Comment: lazy var timer:Timer = {
        return Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            let darkGrey = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.05, green: 0.05, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1.0)
            self.aLabelThatIsRed.textColor = darkGrey
        }
    }()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put that code `let timer ...` in a instance's method (ex: viewWillAppear)

OR change to this:

```
var timer: Timer {
    return Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { 
        [weak self] timer in
        let darkGrey = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.05, green: 0.05, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1.0)
        self?.aLabelThatIsRed.textColor = darkGrey
    }
}
```

The reason is: aLabelThatIsRed is an instance's variable (property of ViewController), but in your current code, it is used outside of an instance's method. It is the same as  you call ViewController.aLabelThatIsRed, which result the same error you have. Doing my solution 1 or 2 will put that variable in an instance's method.

Comment: I can see why that would be more clean... but do you know why exactly?

Comment: @GeovanniEscobar I put explanation in my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have a strong reference cycle capturing `self`.

Answer (score 0):

A `let` variable is initialized before the `ViewController` is initialized. Hence, `self`, that is the `ViewController`, isn't available at the time the timer and its block is created. And hence, you're not able to access `aLabelThatIsRed`, which is a property on the `ViewController`.

One fix would be to convert the `let` to a `lazy var`. This would work because lazy var is initialized after the ViewController is initialized, hence, self would be available. You might also have to explicitly do a `self.aLabelThatIsRed` since you're referring to it inside a closure

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var aLabelThatIsRed: UILabel!

    lazy var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        let darkGrey = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.05, green: 0.05, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1.0)
        self?.aLabelThatIsRed.textColor = darkGrey
    }
```

Comment: You have a strong reference cycle capturing `self`.

Comment: @Alexander fixed